# Change website width to conform to UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Every once in a while my Web View will encounter a site that is zoomed in too far, I don't care about vertical scrolling but horizontal scrolling can be very annoying. My code thus far:

```
-(void)zoomToFit
{
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSInteger height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                     @"document.body.scrollHeight"] integerValue];

NSInteger width = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"document.body.scrollWidth"] integerValue];

NSLog(@"%d  %d",height,width);
}
```

As you can see I have the height and width of the page I just don't know how to change the "zoom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `contentSize` of `UIWebView`'s `UIScrollView`. Like:

```
[yourWebView.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width,height)];
```

Hope this will work for you.